# 301 Redirects not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect every request from `http://` to `https://` and from `www.example.com` to `example.com`. In addition, a redirect from the IP address to `https://example.com` would be awesome.

I managed to redirect the `http://` requests to `https://` but unfortunately I always fail with the redirect of the www to the non-www site.

Here's my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/foo2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/foo2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas why it isn't working. And how do I redirect the IP address correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/foo2 [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/foo2/$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` is literally just the hostname, not the hostname plus the path (ie. `/foo2`). You mentioned in comments that the site (and .htaccess file) are in a subdirectory (`/foo2`), so something like the following should suffice:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/foo2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above condition states that if the `HTTP_HOST` starts `www.` then redirect.

> a redirect from the IP address to `https://example.com` would be awesome.

As above, you just need to check the `HTTP_HOST` for the IP address. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =123.123.123.123
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/foo2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Using the `=` operator, this checks for lexicographical equality, ie. not a regex, so no need to escape the dots.

### Combined rule for all 3 instances...

However, this can all be combined into a more compact - single - ruleset. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =123.123.123.123
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If the request is *not* HTTPS, or starts with `www.` or is the servers' IP address then redirect...

Comment: Thanks a lot, the combined rules work just fine. PS: I do need the subdirectory because the website is located inside there.

Comment: Is this .htaccess file also located in that subdirectory? (Or in the document root?)

Comment: It's in the subdirectory

Comment: Oh I just noticed, that the IP redirect doesn't do it's job :/

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to the subdirectory (although this does not affect the "combined rule"). Are you on a dedicated server with its own IP address, or a shared server? Only if you have a dedicated server is the IP address redirect likely to work.

Comment: I have no idea why (yesterday it worked for some time) but unfortunately Safari blocks the loading of the website, because there were too many redirects. Have you any idea on how to get it working? I took your combined code without the IP Address because I only have a hosting on a shared server.

Comment: "it worked for some time" - This sounds like a caching issue? (301 redirects will be cached by the browser, including redirects previously made in error.) Or perhaps a conflict with existing directives? Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file? Or any other .htaccess files? The above directives by themselves should not result in a redirect loop. Btw, if you remove the `RewriteCond` for the IP address check then you should also remove the `OR` flag from the preceding `RewriteCond` directive.

Comment: I'm an idiot... The issue came up because I forgot to remove the OR. I still have to learn a lot to write .htaccess files... Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted" (tick on the left of the answer) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers that you find useful. Much appreciated. Thanks.